# DateTime being forced to UnixTime in BigQuery

Tags: datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm having some problems with an upload to BQ and so I thought it would be a good idea to post here asking for advice. I have a dataset of medical information (yes, I have approval to put it up on BQ). The dataset contains things like the overall finding of the test and other string-type information, which BQ has no problem accepting. Here is the Schema we are currently expecting in BQ

```
a                       STRING       NULLABLE   
b                       STRING       NULLABLE   
c                       STRING       NULLABLE   
d                       STRING       NULLABLE   
reportDate              DATETIME     NULLABLE   
f                       STRING       NULLABLE
```

Here is the dypes of each column from the Pandas dataframe that I export, where the `object` are just strings

```
a                                object
b                                object
c                                object
d                                object
reportDate               datetime64[ns]
f                                object
```

However, it REALLY doesn't like the Datatime I have. It will only accept it I set the TYPE in the Schema as "INTEGER" or if it let BQ infer the type, in which case it converts it to an integer itself. Anything else, and it will fail. Here are the 3 errors I get when I tell it to accept datetime as the field type

```
 Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. 
 Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0 
 Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Could not convert non-string JSON value to DATETIME type. Field: reportDate; Value: 1501874143000
```

My team wants it as a datetime because it it much easier for them to work with in that format. Does anyone have any advice on what to do?

I've included the first 5 elements from the Pandas series I use, and we can see the dtype is datetime64. I've even filtered down onto ONLY these 5 examples to be uploaded to BQ, but this problem still occurs.

```
 0   2017-08-04 19:15:43 
 1   2017-08-04 16:36:46 
 2   2017-08-04 19:15:47 
 3   2017-08-04 16:36:51 
 4   2017-08-04 17:42:21 
Name: reportDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Thank you for anyone who can offer some help!

Comment: How are you uploading to BQ? in which format?

Comment: I'm using the User Interface and the file format is Newline Delimted JSON

Comment: Do you use a specific schema when loading the file? If you use, can you provide it?

Comment: Try to change the DATETIME to TIMESTAMP

Comment: I just edited the post to indicate the Schema and dytpes of my data. I also tried TIMESTAMP and get the error: 

Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of 1501874143000000000 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch. The range of valid timestamp values is [0001-01-1 00:00:00, 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999]; error in writing field reportDate

Comment: I dont know exactely the impact it brings to your model, but if you load it as an INTEGER, you can consult it as a TIMESTAMP using USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(field) in your query.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code is saving this field as a epoch date (unix time).
Since its not possible to load an `INTEGER` field as a `TIMESTAMP` in `BigQuery`, I can advice you two possible things:

1. You can load the field as an `INTEGER` and use BigQuery's `USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP` function to convert the epoch date into a TIMESTAMP. You can find some other time functions [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#datetimefunctions)
2. You can try to search if there is any way to save your field with another date format in `Pandas`

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was actually able to get it to upload now. I took some advice from your post: "seems that your code is saving this field as a epoch date". I'm not sure how exactly python/BQ is interpreting the datetime64[ns] the datetime was saved in, so I converted from datetime64[ns] to date within python, then converted to string, and then created the schema to expect a date. That allowed me to create the field as my team is expecting. Thanks for springboarding me here!